# CORS headers not working even after adding in .config file

Tags: angularjs, apache

I am working in AngularJs and making certain cross origin requests for accessing data and all stuff.

For the same,I added the required headers in the `000-default.config` file of Apache Server to allow Cross Origin Requests but it isn't working.
It keeps returning the same error **'XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'domain-name'. No 'Access-Control-Origin' header present and blah blah..**

I tried putting the headers inside the `<IfModule mod_headers.c></IfModule>` but still no difference in output.

I restarted the server too after every attempt. *if thats what you are thinking :P*

**000-default.config file**

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, content-type, Accept"
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
            <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
            </IfModule>
            <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride All
            </Directory>
       </VirtualHost>
```

After searching for answers i came across `adding CORS chrome extension` and `disabling web security` which made it work perfectly but what should I do for production purposes because no one would add extensions and disable security?

**EDIT**

The CORS problem is solved.I dont know how but it happened. I guess i restarted the system so it happened but still there is one issue left.

It works when we add `--disable-web-security` in chrome properties.This works fine in case of development. But how should i go about solving this for production purposes?

Please Help..

Comment: Well, obvious but I might as well ask; Have you restarted apache after making changes?

Comment: yes i did..but to no change in result